# Hibernate 3 SqlQuery is immediately flushed during executeUpdate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, flush

Im using hibernate to do some bulk-ish loading into a table, but found I could improve performance greatly by using a subquery -but because this was an insert statement I had to write this as a native SQLQuery object.  But what I found was that using this method hibernate seems to always flush the query *immediately* when executeUpdate() is called.  This is very inefficient and would perform better if the inserts were bundled and flushed together like other hibernate inserts.

I've played with setting the FlushMode for the session and the Query itself, but nothing has changed.  I couldnt find any specific documentation about how SQLQuery relates to flush mode.

So this code doesnt work as it would seem...

```
Session s = getSession();
s.beginTransaction()
SQLQuery insert = s.createSQLQuery("insert into mytable (mycolumn) values ('myvalue');")
//flush mode should mean that inserts are not flushed until flush() is called
insert.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL); 
insert.executeUpdate();
//insert has already been executed here so flush does nothing
s.flush();
```

Does anyone know if I can force hibernate to queue up the native SQLQuery inserts the same way it does the entity inserts?

Comment: You could use a transaction...

Comment: You are actually calling flush by calling `executeUpdate()` . Open a  transaction after you declare the session with `tx = session.beginTransaction()`  and call  `tx.commit()` whenever you want

Comment: Im not sure I understand.  My code sample is incomplete.  Im definitely creating a transaction.  Also, you're implying I shouldn't call executeUpdate()?   If I dont call executeUpdate() then the SQL will *never* be executed, regardless of whether I call flush/commit/etc.  Creating the Query does not execute it, neither does flush.

Comment: Only executeQuery tells hibernate that you actually want to execute it.  What im pointing out is - that hibernate usually takes an insert like this and keeps in in memory and executes it along with others as a batch, but in this case its executing it immediately, and I want to prevent that.